# Inverse Fourier-cosine transfrom

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Suppose we have a function $F(x)$ given by the integral:
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\frac{\cos(t\log x)}{t}dt\;\;\;\;\;(x>1)$$
This looks tantalizingly like a Fourier-cosine transform of $\frac{f(t)}{t}$. How do we recover $f(t)$ from $F(x)$ !?

Comment: Well, if you do the change of variables $t \mapsto t/\log x $, you get
$$
\int_0^\infty f(t/\log x)/t \cos t \, dt,
$$
which is the cosine transform of $f(\cdot/\log x)/t$. That should allow you to recover $f(t /\log x)/t$, and consequently $f$.